# Divi Anchor Links from another page

Tags: url, menu, anchor

I set up a page that has all of my previous pages in one with anchor links that allow the user to scroll quickly down the page with ease. That works fine.

However, each section is it's own page and I have the individual page links listed in my footer. I've created each menu link referencing back to the section of the page but the only one that works is the first one "About." The rest of the links FAQ, Privacy Policy, Disclaimer, Disclosure, and Contact receive a 404 error.

The URL I'm using for these menu items is https://partyfavorz.com/staging1/about/#about. This works but...

https://partyfavorz.com/staging1/privacy-policy/#privacy-policy does not; nor do the rest of the pages. What am I missing because most of the tutorials say to just put in the #page-name for the link which does not work at all, which is why I use the full URL.

I've got the correct Class ID and know it works because the actual page flows from one section to the next. It's just setting up the outside links within the menu that's not working. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So all of the tutorials are wrong across the board; at least for my site. I changed the menu URL structure to https://partyfavorz.com/staging1/pages/#name

This is not how my permalinks are set up as they are strictly set to {site-name} {post-title}. Theoretically, it should be https://partyfavorz.com/staging1/#name, but whatever. This works.